# Python Twilio Outbound calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have got a Python Django app and I would like to make calls from my Django app by using Twilio. E.g. call a friend and have a conversation with him. I have registered with a Twilio account, however when I am calling a number I can only setup a code to be executed and no "normal call".

However, I do not understand completely the setup and I did some research.

```
import os
from twilio.rest import Client

# Your Account Sid and Auth Token from twilio.com/console
# and set the environment variables. See http://twil.io/secure
account_sid = os.environ['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = os.environ['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.calls.create(
                    url='http://demo.twilio.com/docs/voice.xml',
                    to='+14155551212',
                    from_='+15017122661'
                )

print(call.sid)
```

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

Cheers,
Andi

Answer (score 1):

You can reference the document, [Setting Up Call Forwarding](https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223179908-Setting-Up-Call-Forwarding), which shows you many different way to accomplish that task.